# Set new object equal to otherObject.method()?

Tags: java, http, url, urlconnection

I'm learning java and come across something which confuses me quite a bit. I'm watching a video on an explanation of how http requests work...

```
URL theURL = new URL("http://www.google.com");
**URLConnection theConn = theURL.openConnection();**
```

I understand the first line in that it is just creating a URL object with an actual url as an argument. But I don't understand how in the second line, a URLConnection object is being created and being set equal to a method of the other object, or is that method returning something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is returning a [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) as documented by the [`URL.openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) Javadoc which says (in part)

> Returns a [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) instance that represents a connection to the remote object referred to by the `URL`.